# Error while installating pip for Python3

Tags: apt, 18.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When i tried to install PIP for python3 in Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Command I used:

```
root@DESKTOP-0BEE3OD:/mnt/c# apt install python3-pip

E: Could not read response to hello message from hook [ ! -f /usr/bin/snap ] || /usr/bin/snap advise-snap --from-apt 2>/dev/null || true: Success
```

I am not able to fix this error.

Comment: I started getting this issue with 18.04.02 LTS on Friday too. I can't [un]install any new packages, although apt update/upgrade still work OK.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WSL Ubuntu 18.04 broken apt](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1123159/wsl-ubuntu-18-04-broken-apt)

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem and found an answer here: [Broken APT on WSL 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1123159/wsl-ubuntu-18-04-broken-apt)

Just like in the link I would delete the apt hook first to get apt up and running again:

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20snapd.conf
```

Seems like Snapcraft is the problem here because it is depending on python. I tried to update pip `python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip` and this seemed to mess everything up and I couldn't install any python packages anymore. So I deleted python3 and then the error occured.

Note to self: **Do use apt when upgrading pip**. (At least on ubuntu or simillar distros)